# Link to document library

Tags: 2007, development, list, hyperlink

I have a small issue, basically i have an instance of document library / list, now, how can i get a link to that list / document library?

I'm working with sp 2007

To clarify, here is the code:

```
        SPDocumentLibrary library = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists[listGuid] as SPDocumentLibrary;
```

Now i want to redirect to that particular page .. with the document library, how do i do it programmatically?

```
SPUtility.Redirect(**library.Url**, SPRedirectFlags.UseSource, Context);
```

library.Url, should be the url of the library, how do i get the url?

Comment: What you mean? On the address bar of your browser you should see the link

Comment: updated question with some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to get it.

```
SPList list = web.Lists["TestList"]
string serverRelative Url = list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl;

//If you need full url then you can do this. Not sure GetFullUrl is available in MOSS 2007.
string absoluteUrl = SPUtility.GetFullUrl(web.Site, serverRelativeUrl)
```